# Configure OpenIdConnectOptions

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

In my Startup.cs I'm trying to configure the OpenIdConnectOptions like this:

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), options => options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {
            OnTicketReceived = B2CExtensions.OnTicketReceivedCallback
        });
```

the Callback is a simple static method:

```
public async static Task<Task> OnTicketReceivedCallback(TicketReceivedContext context)
{
    ... 
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error when building the project:

> Error  CS1061  'BinderOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Events' and no accessible extension method 'Events' accepting a first argument of type 'BinderOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

All the examples I found are doing it the same way as I do but apparently something changed since these examples / tutorials...

Can you give me a clue, why this error happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you mark below response as an answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to setup like below instead:

**Startup.cs:**

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup>();
```

**OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup.cs:**

```
public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
  {
    options.ClientId = AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId;
    options.Authority = AzureAdB2COptions.Authority;
    options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = "name" };
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
      OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
      OnRemoteFailure = OnRemoteFailure,
      OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
    };
  }
```

Check out [An ASP.NET Core web app with Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/an-aspnet-core-web-app-with-azure-ad-b2c/) sample for more information about the whole setup.

Comment: I just tried it like that but unfortunately it doesn't work. I also added a callback for the OnTicketReceived event and added breakpoints in all callback methods. After creating a user no breakpoint is hit